# Export shapefile to CSV files by a grid I drew in a image

Tags: qgis, vector, clip

The shapefile is in orange and I need to export them into (1.csv and 2.csv etc...) corresponding to each grid I drew in the map. Is there any way this can be done in a single process?

[image: Map of spandau]

Comment: Why draw the grid in the image? And if you drew it yourself, is it really necessary to use exactly that grid, or could you build a new grid?

Comment: what do you mean a new grid? Am new to qgis .. could you please explain :-)   ... But the idea is to split the shapefile into chunks and save them as .csv files

Comment: Do you need exactly this grid, or could it be slightly different?

Comment: could be slightly different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a grid (`vector -> research tools -> create grid`) covering the area of the city you need to be covered. Your gridsize seems to be about 100 by 100 m, use this for vertical and horizontal distances. Make sure you get `polgyons`, not any other type of grid.
2. Make sure your grid-polygons all have an ID.
3. Use `vector -> data management tools -> join attributes by location` to add the ID of your grid-polygons to your point layer.
4. Again from the data management tools choose `split vector layer` and use the added ID-field as a base for splitting your point layer into small chunks.

You might need to convert to `csv` manually.